# Match a line and remove it and append lines below it in Unix shell

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a file containing following line

```
<datasource file name>: {"project": "<PROJECT NAME>", "db_config": "<DATASOURCE NAME>", "schedules": ["DAILY/INCREMENTAL"], "groups": {"All Users":"None","Viewer":"ViewerAccessType","DIY":"DIYAccessType"}}
```

I am thinking to use variables for

```
<PROJECT NAME> = project1
<DATASOURCE NAME> = Default
```

and then

I want to remove this line and add following lines same location in the file

```
view1: {"project": "project1", "db_config": "Default", "schedules": ["DAILY/INCREMENTAL"],"groups": {"All Users":"None"}}
view2: {"project": "project1", "db_config": "Default", "schedules": ["DAILY/INCREMENTAL"],"groups": {"All Users":"None"}}
```

Could anyone please suggest?

I tried with

```
sed -ir "s|^<datasource file name>:.*|view1: $datasource_var|" $SITE_CONFIG_PROPERTIES_FILE
```

but it replaces only one line how to add more lines as above?

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. Please visit [the help center about formatting code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), learn a bit of formatting and format your question such that it becomes readable.

Comment: A great guide for asking questions that get quick, effective answers in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Also, use a json-aware tool like `jq` to parse json. Format your post and add more examples of input, desired output, and what you tried, and we'll get you fixed up.

Comment: does the input file contain the literal string `<datasource file name>`? if not, please update the question with actual examples of what's in this field (before the first `:`); or do we not care what's in this field as long as the `project` and `db_config` fields match the contents of the (`bash`) variables?

Comment: the 2x new lines look like a copy of the line to be deleted (minus the `Viewer` and `DIY` fields); is the intention to copy parts of the deleted line to create the 2x new lines? or do you have a hard-coded string (that has no relationship to the line to be deleted) that's to be used to create the 2x new lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand all the details but you could use `sed` append (`a`) and delete (`d`) commands instead of substitute (`s`). Example with GNU `sed`:

```sh
sed '/^<datasource file name>:/{a\
view1: {"project": "project1"..."All Users":"None"}}
;a\
view2: {"project": "project1"..."All Users":"None"}}
;d;}' file.txt
```

Note: it seems to work (at least on your example) even with the outdated BSD `sed` that comes with macOS.

You could also use `awk`. Example with GNU `awk`:

```sh
awk -v a='view1: {"project": "project1"..."All Users":"None"}}' \
    -v b='view2: {"project": "project1"..."All Users":"None"}}' \
    '/^<datasource file name>:/ {print a; print b; next} {print}' file.txt
```

Note: same remark as for `sed`, it seems to work on your examples with the outdated BSD `awk` that comes with macOS.